# Optional HTTP Post parameters JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a filtration function, a lot of checkboxes and dropdowns. When user selects multiple check boxes and selects the dropdown values they click on the **"Filter Now"** button.

That button then carries out a POST request to my API and pass along the filtration options as the parameters and return the data from MongoDB.

Heres my code:

```
factory.getFilteredProjects = function(regions, services, sector){

  return $http.post('/user/test',{
      region: regions,
      sol: services,
      sec: sector
  }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available

        console.log("this is the response data " + data);
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });

  };    
     return factory;
 });
```

In the above code you can see I have **3 parameters** *(regions, services, sector)*

Now the user only might want to filter the data by:

1. Regions or Sector
2. Just Regions
3. Just Services
4. Services and Regions

**And So On!**

**My question:**

How can I pass options parameters with my POST regions. ***At the moment I have to send all 3 parameters to get data back. If I don't send all 3 then I don't get any data back.*** Only the ones the user actually interacted with so basically something like:

```
// This is just to get my point across.
function(a || b || c){
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Testing my API through POSTMan. As you can see I only sent 2 parameters and got a 200 status back and i am also getting the correct data back.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified the JSON is shaped the way you expect on the wire, using a your browser dev tools or something list postman?  What is returned from the server (ie, what is the HTTP status code, etc.)?

Comment: @Noel thanks for the comment. When i use POSTMan I can 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 parameters and I still get data back. The API can handle it on the server.

Comment: Then you just need to detect which ones the user actually interacted, and send only them.

Comment: @AlexBlex any suggestions on how I can do that? Also see update on my question please.

Comment: @Noel Please see my update on the question.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, you see a 200 HTTP status code from the server, and the response contains the data you'd expect?  And when you say "you don't get data", do you mean the promise resolves, but the `data` parameter in the success function is `null`?

Comment: @Noel Testing through PostMan I get the data I expect. Testing through my own code the promise resolves. I get no errors but the DATA parameters returns Null. After doing `data.length' the output is 0.

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn, sorry I am not an angularian, but I assume it should be related to data binding. Anyway, I believe your factory sends some junk instead of expected values, or is not being invoked until all 3 params are changed. You can check it in chrome devtools in network tab. I removed mongodb tag to avoid further confusion.

Comment: I see your screenshot with the 200 HTTP status, so that's good, but I don't see the response data.  I'm not 100% convinced your server is actually sending the data in the response.  Can you share the http response? One possible issue (at least that won't be consistent w/your angular app) is that you are sending x-www-form-urlencoded.  You should select raw and pass json.

Comment: @Noel The response data is coming back as JSON, I can see the response  , because the response is private data I can't really share it. I think the issue is that my HTTP POST function requires all 3 parameters. If somehow I can only pass the parameters that the user interacted with would be really good. But I can't figure out how.

Comment: @Noel see my answer please. thank you

Comment: @AlexBlex see my answer please. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can just give an object in parameter instead of three string. Like this you can control the number of POST parameters instead of have some of them undefined.

**EDIT : I suggest to do the filtering in your service. Like this, you don't have to complexify your code on each controller :**

```
factory.getFilteredProjects = function(params){

  // remove empty value or empty array
  angular.forEach(params, function(value, key) {
    if( ! value || value.length === 0 ) {
      delete params[key];
    }
  })

  return $http.post('/user/test', params).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available

        console.log("this is the response data " + data);
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });

  };    
     return factory;
 });

getFilteredProjects({ region: 'test', sec: 'sector' })
```

Comment: You right. I just copy/paste and change Lorenzo's code :)

Comment: that's fine...is note for OP also. But should be mentioned

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the Info. I'll change the code.

Answer (score 0):

so after doing some research, a few cups of coffee and couple of swear words later I got this working.

But heres a note:

First thanks to **Yoann Prot** your suggestion was a huge help!

**This is my initial solution, I will NOT be accepting my own answer. Because there might be a better solution to this and I would like someone to post an answer/comment if they think it can be improved**

So my if you read the comments above you know my API was able to handle multiple or flexible number parameters. The issue was my HTTP Post function required all parameters to be present.

As ***Alex Blex*** suggested in the comments that:

> Then you just need to detect which ones the user actually interacted, and send only them

And thats exactly what I did.

I created a **filter object** to which I added key/value pairs of only the options that the user interacted with and passed that whole filter object as the parameter. This made my parameters for the HTTP Post request much more flexible.

Heres the code:

```
 var filterObj = {};

    var form = document.getElementById("regionPicker");
    var servicesForm = document.getElementById("servicesPicker");

    var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var arr = [];

    var servicesInput = servicesForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var servicesArr = [];

    for (var i = 0;  i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
         // Take only those inputs which are checkbox
        if (inputs[i].type === "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) {
                 arr.push(inputs[i].value);
         }
     }

    for (var i = 0;  i < servicesInput.length; i += 1) {
         // Take only those inputs which are checkbox
        if (servicesInput[i].type === "checkbox" && servicesInput[i].checked) {
                 servicesArr.push(servicesInput[i].value);
          }
       }


 // here arr contains an array of filter options selected by user
 filterObj.region = (arr.length > 0) ? arr:"";

 // here serviceArr contains an array of another filter options selected by user
 filterObj.sol = (servicesArr.length > 0) ? servicesArr:"";
```

And finally pass the filterObj as the parameter:

```
factory.getFilteredProjects = function(filterObj){

  return $http.post('/user/test',filterObj)
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       console.log("this is the response data " + data.length);
    })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
  };
```

**So far all the tests have been successful. But I repeat if you know a better solution please let me know or if you think this solution has drawbacks or issues or is just bad practice please let me know.**

Thanks!